# Python regex group sentences by person's name

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have the following text:

```
"- Nike: Hey, where are you?\n10/6/20, 8:51 - Mike: Soon\n10/6/20, 8:55 - Nike: how are you guy?\n10/4/20, 8:55 - Mike: It's okay\n10/4/20, 9:05"
```

I'd like to make 2 lists like the following:

```
nike = ["Hey, where are you?", "how are you guy?"]
mike = ["Soon", "It's okay"]
```

Any idea how I could do such thing please?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

s = "- Nike: Hey, where are you?\n10/6/20, 8:51 - Mike: Soon\n10/6/20, 8:55 - Nike: how are you guy?\n10/4/20, 8:55 - Mike: It's okay\n10/4/20, 9:05"

out = {}
for name, sentence in re.findall(r'([A-Za-z]+):\s*(.*)$', s, flags=re.M):
    out.setdefault(name, []).append(sentence)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Nike': ['Hey, where are you?', 'how are you guy?'], 'Mike': ['Soon', "It's okay"]}
```